# Configuring destination NAT nftables entire subnet

Tags: nat, nftables

Basically what I need is to change all packets destined to one subnet to a different subnet

I need this because my router has 2 VPNs and both of them use the same ip range [out of my control]

This is my current config, but it doesn't work, packets have their destination unchanged

```
table inet nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;

        ip daddr 192.168.5.0/24 dnat to 192.168.1.0/24
    }
}
```

My main goal is to have packets with destination `192.168.5.0` be forwarded to `wg1` and `192.168.1.0` to `wg0`

Answer (score 1):

In current versions, use 'ip prefix map':

```
ip daddr … dnat ip prefix to ip daddr map { 192.168.5.0/24 : 192.168.1.0/24 }
```

In older versions, use bitwise operations:

```
ip daddr … dnat to ip addr & 0.0.0.255 | 192.168.1.0
```

However, DNAT won't be enough, because – as the chain name implies – the rewriting is done before routing decisions are made. Once the system gets to routing, well, it still has two conflicting 192.168.1.0/24 interfaces.

I think you'll need to additionally set *packet marks* on 192.168.5.0/24 before applying NAT (e.g. in a `raw` chain), then use policy routing via `ip rule` to select a whole different routing table for the second VPN (wg1).

Comment: I modified the line like you said `ip daddr 192.168.5.0/24 dnat ip prefix to ip daddr map { 192.168.5.0/24 : 192.168.1.0/24 }`, and I know that this alone won't fix the problem, but using tcpdump I can see the packets have their destination ip unchanged

Comment: What kind of packets? If you're continuously pinging something on the other end, you should at least flush the conntrack states that have the old translation (or lack thereof) cached; `conntrack -F` or `conntrack -D -p icmp` or something such.

Comment: I was pinging, but not continuously. I checked the connection was not tracked, and the IPs are still not being converted.